# Concurrency - why using a nested subclass for final static fields?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to understand a change that was made to the JDK:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/223be1d3494f

Prior to this change, double checked locking was used to ensure thread-safety, which lead to issues.

Why are they using yet another subclass? Why are they not simply using `static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();` in `StrictMath`?

Or, more general, why is this so:

> The standard technique is to have a nested subclass with a final field
>   initialized on demand (lazily)

(from https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6470700)

Comment: *"Why are they not simply using static final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();"*--maybe to save a memory. `Math.random()` is used rarely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the *initialize-on-demand holder idiom* as described in Item 48 of *Effective Java*.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

See also: [Correct implementation of initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604243/correct-implementation-of-initialization-on-demand-holder-idiom)

Comment: Ok, so the only reason to not use a static final field directly in StrictMath would be to have it initialized lazily, it is not strictly needed for concurrency?

Comment: @Polygnome It's to get *both* lazy initialization *and* thread-safety at lower cost / greater simplicity than using double-checked locking.  (DCL used to be unsafe; as of Java 5, it's merely complicated and error-prone.)

Comment: Ok, thanks, if you add that last comment to the answer its perfect ;) Knowing the name of the idiom already helped me much finding additional information.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use a static final field in the parent you would not have a lazy initialization.
The static fields of a class are initialized when the class is first used and thus loaded.
So if you would have a static final field in the parent class, it would get initialized as soon as the outer class is referenced.

By using this idiom you have lazy loading, because the static final field of the inner class is only initialized when first used and thus needed.

Comment: The question was *why*, I don't argue that it does, and specific, why it doesn't use a static final field in the parent.